# jQuery | Filter elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filter, push

May be you can help me:

My functions:

```
 getMyUsers : function(callback){ /*- get users every 5 seconds*/
    ...
    ...

    success: function(r) {          
          var users = [];
          for(var i=0; i< r.users.length;i++){
             if(r.users[i]){
               users.push(render('user',r.users[i]));   
             }
          }
          jQuery('#chatUsers').append(users.join(''));  
    }

        url: 'path/handler.php?action=getusers';
 }
```

This function get my users from the server. It comes as json string like:

```
 {
    "users": [{
        "name": "username_temp",
        "last_activity": "16:29:16",
        "gravatar": "thumb_1546278d532ea4c1cddc7a4b.jpg",
        "status": "",
        "usertype": "M",
        "typing": "0"
    }, {
        "name": "admin",
        "last_activity": "16:29:16",
        "gravatar": "thumb_7d41870512afee28b70d5d91.jpg",
        "status": "",
        "usertype": "M",
        "typing": "0"
    }],
    "total": "2"
}



     render: function(template,params){
      switch(template){
       case "user";
        arr = ['<div class="user" id="user-',params.name,'">',params.name,'</div>'];
       break; 
      }
      return arr.join('');
     }
```

My HTML container:

```
<div id="chatUsers"></div>
```

How should I change my functions to:

1. Remove (filter) user(s) from my div container if it not comes in the string.
2. If my user already in the container skip.
3. If this is a new user just append it to the container.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you need to close the single-quoted string after `id="user-` in your `render` function.

Comment: It's closed: id="user-,params.name,'"

Comment: look again -- count the single quotes, you have an odd number of them.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to synchronize the server list with the local list of users, but #2 is the sticking point: Does it really benefit you to skip users already in the container? I'm not convinced it does, and if it doesn't, you can skip most of the loop and do `jQuery('#chatUsers').replaceWith(users.join(''));`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to remove users from the DIV if they're not in the JSON; you want to skip adding them if they are in the JSON; and you want to append them if they're not in the DIV.

Well, why not just replace the contents of the DIV instead of appending to it?

```
jQuery('#chatUsers').html(users.join(''));
```

Comment: It's my old solution and it works (But I can see a blink effect when I just replace my html in container). But I need to use .remove and .append solution.